# Ajuste de array_multisort no PHP

Tags: php, array

opa, tudo certo?! Peguei este script pra dar continuidade e tem o select que me traz os dados do banco. Estou com dificuldade em fazer o multisort.

```
<?php

$sql = mysql_query("select if(extra50 = 0, '', extra50) AS extra50, if(extra100 = 0, '', extra100) AS extra100, if(extra50not = 0, '', extra50not) AS extra50not, if(extra100not = 0, '', extra100not) AS extra100not, ds_nome from resumida_" . $cd_ano . " where cd_mes = " . $cd_mes . " ", $conexao);
while ($RR = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    $motorista[$m]['nome'] = strtoupper($RR["ds_nome"]);
    $motorista[$m]['hr50'] = $RR["extra50"];
    $motorista[$m]['hr100'] = $RR["extra100"];
    $motorista[$m]['hr51'] = $RR["extra50not"];
    $motorista[$m]['hr101'] = $RR["extra100not"];

    if ($cd_ordenar == 50) {
        foreach ($motorista as $res)
            $sortAux[] = $res['hr50'];
    }
    if ($cd_ordenar == 51) {
        foreach ($motorista as $res)
            $sortAux[] = $res['hr51'];
    }
    if ($cd_ordenar == 60) {
        foreach ($motorista as $res)
            $sortAux[] = $res['hr60'];
    }
    if ($cd_ordenar == 100) {
        foreach ($motorista as $res)
            $sortAux[] = $res['hr100'];
    }
    if ($cd_ordenar == 101) {
        foreach ($motorista as $res)
            $sortAux[] = $res['hr101'];
    }
    if ($cd_ordem == 1) {
        array_multisort($sortAux, SORT_DESC, $motorista);
    }
    if ($cd_ordem == 0) {
        array_multisort($sortAux, SORT_ASC, $motorista);
    }
    foreach ($motorista as $vl) {

        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>" . $vl['nome'] . "</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>" . MinToHrMinB($vl['hr50']) . "</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>" . MinToHrMinB($vl['hr100']) . "</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>" . MinToHrMinB($vl['hr51']) . "</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>" . MinToHrMinB($vl['hr101']) . "</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";

        $tot50 += $vl['hr50'];
        $tot51 += $vl['hr51'];
        $tot100 += $vl['hr100'];
        $tot101 += $vl['hr101'];
    }
}
```

O $cd_ordenar e o $cd_ordem vem de um cabeçalho pra ordenar conforme descrito no script. Tentei algumas maneiras imprimindo na tela pra ver como ia progredindo mas não obtive sucesso. Ele simplesmente não ordena. Mantem sempre o mesmo esquema de resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei resolvendo mudando a forma que o array era criado e jogando o resto do código pra fora do while():

```
while($RR = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

    $motorista[] = array('nome'=>strtoupper($RR["ds_nome"]), 'hr50'=>$RR["extra50"], 'hr100'=>$RR["extra100"], 'hr51'=>$RR["extra50not"], 'hr101'=>$RR["extra100not"] );

}

if($cd_ordenar == 50){foreach($motorista as $res) $sortAux[] = $res['hr50'];}
if($cd_ordenar == 51){foreach($motorista as $res) $sortAux[] = $res['hr51'];}
if($cd_ordenar == 60){foreach($motorista as $res) $sortAux[] = $res['hr60'];}
if($cd_ordenar == 100){foreach($motorista as $res) $sortAux[] = $res['hr100'];}
if($cd_ordenar == 101){foreach($motorista as $res) $sortAux[] = $res['hr101'];}

if($cd_ordem == 1){array_multisort($sortAux, SORT_DESC, $motorista);}
if($cd_ordem == 0){array_multisort($sortAux, SORT_ASC, $motorista);}
foreach($motorista as $vl){
    if($vl['hr50'] != 0 || $vl['hr51'] != 0 || $vl['hr60'] != 0 || $vl['hr100'] != 0 || $vl['hr101'] != 0){
        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>".$vl['nome']."</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>".MinToHrMinB($vl['hr50'])."</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>".MinToHrMinB($vl['hr100'])."</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>".MinToHrMinB($vl['hr51'])."</td>";
        $html .= "<td align='center'>".MinToHrMinB($vl['hr101'])."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";

        $tot50 += $vl['hr50'];
        $tot51 += $vl['hr51'];
        $tot100 += $vl['hr100'];
        $tot101 += $vl['hr101'];
    }
}
```